# Android convert/compile C++ as Neon

Tags: android, c++, opencv, neon

I am currently writing a simple Android program using C++ with the help of JNI and OpenCV.
The input is a image stored as a Mat.
Instead of using OpenCV's normalize function, I wish to write my own normalize function in C++.
From what I know, there is support for NEON.
However, looking at HelloNeon sample in the NDK folder, I realised that the code is written in NEON instrinsics.

Question:
Is there a way to directly compile my C++ code into NEON code?
i.e. I wish to avoid writing my function in NEON intrinsics.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out http://www.yeppp.info/ by Marat Dukhan.  I have not used it yet but though.

Answer (score 1):

Largely depends on the compiler. Both gcc and clang do support "automatic vectorizing" in recent versions, but the quality of the generated code is very variable - mostly depending on the actual source code. As always, the compiler is firstly responsible for generating correct code, secondly to generate fast/efficient code. If in doubt, go for "safe" option.

It should, however, work to use `-mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize`.

I do expect that you need to "massage" the code to make it vectorize well, however - at least that's my experience on x86, where the compiler will attempt to build SSE instructions when vectorizing. It succeeds in fairly simple cases, but falls back to "regular code" when the code is more complex. Later compilers do work better than older versions, as a rule.

If you really need to get good vectorizing results, you will probably end up needing to use Neon intrinsics.

Comment: To be fair: if he wants good results he has to write the neon loops in assembler. The code generated from the intrinsics is still bad.

Comment: im not certain what NDK uses for its compiler though. my current workflow is as follows: write C++ -> run ndk-build -> run ant -> install apk. where do I need to insert the NEON option? it would probably help to mention that im using ubuntu 12.04 to do this.

Comment: What host-system you are using shouldn't make any difference. NDK uses a version of gcc - which one depends on which version of NDK. You will probably have to fiddle with the makefiles to build your code to make it use these flags, as I doubt Neon code and vectorizing will be enabled by default. But I fail to see any other option.

Comment: Im currently using android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64.  I'm not too sure how to go about fiddling with the makefiles to enable compiling from C++ to NEON since the sample given was coded in instrinsics. Could you point me in the right direction? I am aware that there are two makefiles. One is named Android.mk and the other Application.mk. I have no idea which and how to change.

Comment: Sorry, not sure, as I don't have an NDK on my home machine (and don't do SO at work!)